# Electrical layout drawing application for Mac

Tags: macos, software-rec

Do you know the free application, that lets me to quickly draw the layout of electrical network ?

Answer (score 1):

I'm using [OmniGraffle](http://www.omnigroup.com/products/omnigraffle/) for that. It's not free but it's not expensive either and it's worth it.

You can use the [electronic circuit symbols IEC 606007](http://graffletopia.com/stencils/494)